# using wget to download files of a certain type nested within a directory

Tags: wget

I am trying to download only the .nc files from a directory structure that looks something like this:

```
+ podaac-tools.jpl.nasa.gov/drive/files/allData/ghrsst/data/GDS2/L4/GLOB/JPL/MUR/v4.1/2020/
    + 001
        + 001-MUR-GLOB-v02.0-fv04.1.nc
        + 001-MUR-GLOB-v02.0-fv04.1.nc.md5
    + 002
        + 002-MUR-GLOB-v02.0-fv04.1.nc
        + 002-MUR-GLOB-v02.0-fv04.1.nc.md5
    + 003
        + 003-MUR-GLOB-v02.0-fv04.1.nc
        + 003-MUR-GLOB-v02.0-fv04.1.nc.md5
    + 004
        + 004-MUR-GLOB-v02.0-fv04.1.nc
        + 004-MUR-GLOB-v02.0-fv04.1.nc.md5
```

I'm using:

```
wget -r -nd -nc -A "*.nc" https://podaac-tools.jpl.nasa.gov/drive/files/allData/ghrsst/data/GDS2/L4/GLOB/JPL/MUR/v4.1/2020/
```

Whenever I use the `-A "*.nc"` or `-A.nc` flags, the command gets rejected with:

```
--2020-03-30 18:20:29--  https://podaac-
tools.jpl.nasa.gov/drive/files/allData/ghrsst/data/GDS2/L4/GLOB/JPL/MUR/v4.1/2020/
Resolving podaac-tools.jpl.nasa.gov (podaac-tools.jpl.nasa.gov)... 137.78.248.120
Connecting to podaac-tools.jpl.nasa.gov (podaac-tools.jpl.nasa.gov)|137.78.248.120|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Authentication selected: Basic realm="PODAAC_Drive"
Reusing existing connection to podaac-tools.jpl.nasa.gov:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 48529 (47K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.tmp’

index.html.tmp      100%[===================>]  47.39K  --.-KB/s    in 0.1s    

2020-03-30 18:20:30 (492 KB/s) - ‘index.html.tmp’ saved [48529/48529]

Removing index.html.tmp since it should be rejected.

FINISHED --2020-03-30 18:20:30--
Total wall clock time: 1.4s
Downloaded: 1 files, 47K in 0.1s (492 KB/s)
```

Otherwise, if I don't use the `-A "*.nc"` or `-A.nc` flags, I get a download that includes all the files in the directories, which is more than I want.

Answer (score 0):

`-R = --reject` may help.

try:

```
wget -r -nd -nc -R="*.md5" https://podaac-tools.jpl.nasa.gov/drive/files/allData/ghrsst/data/GDS2/L4/GLOB/JPL/MUR/v4.1/2020/
```